# HTML 5 generator for Yeoman?

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman

Can you recommend me some good HTML5 generator for Yeoman?

This is the first time I'm scaffolding website via Yeoman and I'm unfamiliar with good generators and there are so many of them.

I'm building HTML5/CSS/JS/jQ website.

Comment: Do you just want something that kick starts a single HTML page for you? With no other frameworks etc? I'm getting the feeling that you might have something else in mind other than what the question indicates? In terms of the HTML5 generators listed on the yeoman project page, there is literally only the one that claims to be an HTML5 generator. generator-h5bp... but the generator hasn't been active for over a year (the html5-boilerplate project is still fairly active though).

Comment: @RohanBüchner generator-h5bp is updated along with h5bp, because it uses h5bp as a submodule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found one cool generator with HTML5 boilerplate, jquery and Bootstrap(optional) and it works just fine for me https://github.com/yeoman/generator-webapp

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [generator-h5bp](https://github.com/h5bp/generator-h5bp) scaffolds [HTML5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/).

I strongly suggest this one, because HTML5 Boilerplate has an awesome [documentation](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/v4.3.0/doc/TOC.md).